# is SAAS application development different from a non SAAS application development?

Tags: architecture, web-development-server, saas

I am building a platform that is going to be used by organizations, each have their own users and that is going to be on subscription basis. I want to know if the development part of the application is different from a non saas app. what differences i should take in consideration ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce the idea of row-level security early.  Put a robust authorization system in-place at the very start implementing RBAC at the lowest detail rows of your data-store.  At the very least a customer id, and make sure ALL access to the data is qualified by that customer id at a very low level.

Waiting on this will make a nightmare when you try and retro-fit all your database access (including simple lookups) to qualify it by the customer who is logged in.

This is the biggest fundamental difference between SaaS and single-customer system development.  Scaling factors and such also exist, but could equally exist in a non-SaaS solution as well.